# Strange Issue after upgrade 3.10 to 3.20 in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

After upgrade 3.10 to 3.20 , nopcommerce is not building dll files properly. i cant see the changes i made in my plugins. what i figure out is that in web project there are dll files of plugins we create, it does not re-build these files. i dont know why. I have applied the latest patch to VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like problem with Visual Studio. There was however change to how NopCommerce is built, instead of batch files you build and publish from within Visual Studio.

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio
2. Re-build the entire solution
3. Publish the "Nop.Web" project from Visual Studio
   P.S. When publishing ensure that configuration is set to "Release"

Also solution was upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 format, maybe there is backward compatibility issue.